# Convert pytorch model (.pth) to coreml

Tags: python, pytorch, coreml, coremltools

I am new to pytorch and coreml. I have a pre-trained pytorch model(.pth file) downloaded from https://github.com/zhangboshen/A2J and I want to convert it into coreml model to use for ios application.I loaded the model as below.

```
 import coremltools as ct
 import torch
 import torch.nn as nn

 model = torch.load('/Users/sarojraut/Downloads/side.pth',map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
 example_input = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224) 

 traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, example_input)
```

But it gives error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
 traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, dummy_input)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-   packages/torch/jit/_trace.py", line 846, in trace
 name = _qualified_name(func)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site- packages/torch/_jit_internal.py", line 1145, in _qualified_name
 raise RuntimeError("Could not get name of python class object")
 RuntimeError: Could not get name of python class object
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error because you're ONLY loading the model's weights or dictionary. A PyTorch model has two main parts: the architecture (the model's class) and the weights/dictionary. They are usually separate.

To load the model, follow these steps:

1. Create an instance of the model using its original class (the
   architecture). **A2J_model** in your case.
2. Load the model's state dictionary (weights). ***HANDS2017.pth*** used for this demo, but you can use any of the other models provided on the Github repo.

Let's put this into action by utilizing the ***hands2017.py***:

```
import torch
import model as model

# This number provided by the original hands2017.py source code.
keypointsNumber = 21

model_dir = '/Desktop/A2J/HANDS2017.pth'

# Instance of the model.
net = model.A2J_model(num_classes = keypointsNumber)
# load the weights into the model.
net.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_dir, map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
# Put the model in eval mode before tracing.
net.eval()

example_input = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)

# Trace your model..
traced_model = torch.jit.trace(net, example_input)

# Print the traced model to verify if the tracing was successful.
print(traced_model)
```

And this prints out our traced model (torchscript):

```
A2J_model(
  original_name=A2J_model
  (Backbone): ResNetBackBone(
    original_name=ResNetBackBone
    (model): ResNet(
      original_name=ResNet
      (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
      (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
      (maxpool): MaxPool2d(original_name=MaxPool2d)
      (layer1): Sequential(
        original_name=Sequential
        (0): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            original_name=Sequential
            (0): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
        )
      )
      (layer2): Sequential(
        original_name=Sequential
        (0): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            original_name=Sequential
            (0): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
        )
        (3): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
        )
      )
      (layer3): Sequential(
        original_name=Sequential
        (0): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            original_name=Sequential
            (0): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
        )
        (3): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
        )
        (4): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
        )
        (5): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
        )
      )
      (layer4): Sequential(
        original_name=Sequential
        (0): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            original_name=Sequential
            (0): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          original_name=Bottleneck
          (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
          (relu): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
        )
      )
      (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(original_name=AdaptiveAvgPool2d)
      (fc): Linear(original_name=Linear)
    )
  )
  (regressionModel): RegressionModel(
    original_name=RegressionModel
    (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
    (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
    (act1): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
    (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
    (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
    (act2): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
    (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
    (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
    (act3): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
    (conv4): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
    (bn4): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
    (act4): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
    (output): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
  )
  (classificationModel): ClassificationModel(
    original_name=ClassificationModel
    (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
    (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
    (act1): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
    (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
    (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
    (act2): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
    (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
    (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
    (act3): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
    (conv4): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
    (bn4): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
    (act4): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
    (output): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
  )
  (DepthRegressionModel): DepthRegressionModel(
    original_name=DepthRegressionModel
    (conv1): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
    (bn1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
    (act1): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
    (conv2): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
    (bn2): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
    (act2): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
    (conv3): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
    (bn3): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
    (act3): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
    (conv4): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
    (bn4): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
    (act4): ReLU(original_name=ReLU)
    (output): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
  )
)
```

This is showing us that the tracing was successful.
One final note, looking at this old repo, wanted to share with you that you achieve both hand and human body poses estimation by leveraging Apple's native API (these are vision based models and maintained by Apple directly):

1. Detecting Hand Poses with Vision: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/detecting_hand_poses_with_vision
2. Detecting Human Body Poses in an Image: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/model_integration_samples/detecting_human_body_poses_in_an_image

Hope this help. Happy conversion to coreml model :)

Comment: If there is no model.A2J_model class, how do we design a wrapper class for the pre-trained model download from internet?